# Trying to convert list of OrderedDict to Dictionary Key value Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, ordereddict

I need to convert ordereddict to dictionary key value.

```
 test = [OrderedDict([('key', 'value'),
              ('name', 'A'),
              ('value', '5')]),
 OrderedDict([('key', 'value'),
              ('name', 'B'),
              ('value', '10')]),
 OrderedDict([('key', 'value'),
              ('name', 'C'),
              ('value', '25')])]here


Desired Output:
{'A': '5', 'B': '10', 'C': '25'}
```

Comment: Please format your code section selecting code and click ctrl+k

Comment: Ok, so what is your *question*?

Comment: `my_dict = {i['name']: i['value'] for i in test}` ?

Comment: Do you actually have a list of ordereddicts, of which each maps ``{'key' :'value', 'name': ..., 'value': ...}``? This looks as if the data should have been read in differently already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test` is essentially a list of dictionaries. Each of those dictionaries has a key `'name'`, which we want to be the key in our output, and a key `'value'`, which we want to be the value in our output. So, we can just use a dict comprehension to iterate through the dicts contained by `test`, and transform each one into a single key-value pair.

```
output = {od['name']: od['value'] for od in test}
# {'A': '5', 'B': '10', 'C': '25'}
```

If you wanted the output to *also* be an `OrderedDict`, then you could feed a generator comprehension to the constructor:

```
output_od = OrderedDict((od['name'], od['value']) for od in test)
# OrderedDict([('A', '5'), ('B', '10'), ('C', '25')])
```